# Display ACF Subfield Values as a Dropdown List

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF Pro and I have a custom post type called team members. I have a repeater field called team_information which has a subfield "member_name"
How can I display all the values of member name in a dropdown list. Right now it just displays the default value. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php
    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
    if( have_rows('team_information') ):
        // loop through the rows of data
        while ( have_rows('team_information') ) : the_row(); 
            $teamMember= get_sub_field('member_name'); 
        endwhile;
    endif;
?>

<select>
    <option value="name" selected><b>Select a Team Member</b></option>
    <?php foreach($teamMember as $team) :?>         
    <option><?php echo $team; ?></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<select>
<option value="name" selected><b>Select a Team Member</b></option>
<?php
      // check if the repeater field has rows of data
if( have_rows('team_information') ):
// loop through the rows of data
while ( have_rows('team_information') ) : the_row(); 
?>        

   <option><?php echo get_sub_field('member_name');  ?></option>
<?php
endwhile;
endif;
?>
</select>
```

if you wish to stick with your code than here is your solution

```
<?php
  $teamMember = array();
  // check if the repeater field has rows of data
  if( have_rows('team_information') ):
  // loop through the rows of data
  while ( have_rows('team_information') ) : the_row(); 

  $teamMember[]= get_sub_field('member_name'); 

 endwhile;
endif;
?>



<select>
  <option value="name" selected><b>Select a Team Member</b></option>
  <?php foreach($teamMember as $team) {?>          
  <option><?php echo $team; ?></option>
  <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: There are multiple ways

Comment: Your second option is only displaying one team member in the dropdown. Let me check the first one.

Comment: No both the options are displaying one artist name in the dropdown list

Comment: There are 9 team members created and at the moment the dropdown list only shows the current artist in the dropdown list and not all of them. If I am on "John's" team page, the only option in the dropdown list is "John". Similarly, if you go on "Mary's" page, the only option in the list is mary.

Comment: Can you share the screenshot i guess meta key  may wrong or something minor misunderstanding is tgere

Comment: Screenshot of what again ? How can I echo all the values of the subfield "member_name" ? Why is it just displaying the current member ?

Comment: screenshot of acf repeater fields and of post where you have more records